# Bootstrap carousel uses two rows when slide changes

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a problem with a over a year old website. At the beginnning of this year I made few modifications and at the same time did npm install, because for some reason all the packages were not found when starting angular (version 5, same problem now with 9). After the npm install I had several issues, most annoying one with carousel. For some reason, when sliding, the carousel slides the next slide from a "row" below and then lifts the slide to its proper place. This effect looks completely stupid and I had no problems with this before. The bootstrap version has not changed from 4.3.1, although I tried 4.4.1 as well.

The code:

```
<div class="event-slider">
    <div id="carouselEvents" *ngIf="events && events.length > 0" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div *ngIf="events" class="carousel-inner">
            <div *ngFor="let event of events; first as isFirst" class="carousel-item" [class.active]="isFirst">
                <span class="one-line"><i>Tuleva tapahtuma:</i></span>
                <!--<div class="one-line" [fittext]="true" [activateOnResize]="true" [maxFontSize]="30"><b>{{event.name}}</b></div>-->
                <span class="one-line">{{event.startDateTime | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}}</span>
                <div class="one-line">
                    <a *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" routerLink="/events/{{event.id}}">Lue lisää</a>
                    <a *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" routerLink="/events">Kaikki tapahtumat</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselEvents" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselEvents" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? A photo describing the problem attached.

[image: carousel_problem]

Comment: Could you maybe give some code snippets of your html? To see the structure of your carousel?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my stupid mistake to forget that. Added to the original post. Some notes about that, the fittext line is commented out, I wanted to see if that contributed to the problem (fittext is an additional library to adjust font size with long texts to fit to the screen, especially with mobile devices), but it didn't. The picture is with that exact code. Problem is the same with or without that line commented. Also the one-line CSS class is just some padding and no-wrap, tested that as well, no effect with or without it.

Comment: I have also same issue..

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution: For some reason, the CSS started acting differently after the update. There was a conflict between the event-slider CSS and carousel-item definitions. I simply removed margin: auto from the carousel-item class and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

This problem also happens when you have the style `clear: both` on the carousel-item